# Script to convert Xml report from jenkins to pdf

Tags: xml, pdf, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins. I've use case that needs to be implemented,

After running the job, the build says Success/Failure and gives us an "XML" report.

We need to write script in Jenkins that XML report needs to convert it into PDF format.

Can you please guide me the steps. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jenkins has native support for file conversion so it sounds like you would have to write some shell scripts to convert the files and then have Jenkins invoke these scripts.

Are you intending to have the pdf look identical to the xml report? Or are you looking to strip away the tags and reformat?

I would look into using python's xml etree module for parsing the xml file and then use a tool like [text2pdf](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/) to convert the txt to a pdf file.

Comment: yeah we need to write shell script to convert the file :/ and would like to strip away the tags and reformat it.

Comment: Ok my recommendation is using python with xml etree or beautiful soup modules to get the text and format it how you would like. Then use program to convert text to pdf